# how to fetch $userPath for only specific few users

Tags: powershell, user-profile

With below `poweshell` script I'm able to see the `userpath` for all user profile.

```
# Get a list of all user profiles
$users = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile

foreach( $user in $users ) {

# Normalize profile name.
$userPath = (Split-Path $user.LocalPath -Leaf).ToLower()

Write-Host $userPath

}
```

How to filter this with specific 2 users, say `user1` and `user2`?

Comment: Powershell help [about_if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? Do you want user profile path at the end? Do you want to cover a case when profile path might have been changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this...

```
# Get a list of all user profiles
$users = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile


foreach( $user in $users ) 
{ (Split-Path $user.LocalPath -Leaf).ToLower() }

# Results
<#
...
networkservice
localservice
systemprofile
#>

# Get a list of specific user profiles
foreach( $user in $users ) 
{ (Split-Path $user.LocalPath -Leaf).ToLower() | Select-String 'networkservice|localservice' }

# Results
<#
networkservice
localservice
#>
```

Or one-liner

```
 (Split-Path (Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile | 
 Where-Object -Property LocalPath -match  'networkservice|localservice').LocalPath -Leaf).ToLower()

# Results
<#
networkservice
localservice
#>
```

Comment: one-liner is just awesome. Exactly looking for same. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the results returned from WMI by using the parameter `filter` and WQL for querying.

**Try this code**

```
$users = Get-WmiObject win32_userprofile -filter 'LocalPath LIKE "%user1%" OR LocalPath LIKE "%user2%"'

foreach( $user in $users ) {

    # Normalize profile name.
    $userPath = (Split-Path $user.LocalPath -Leaf).ToLower()
    Write-Host $userPath
}
```

See [MS documentation for Get-WmiObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1) and look for the `Filter` parameter